# JMeter parameterized tests with large CSV files

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-3.2

I'm using JMeter to run performance tests, but my sample data set is huge.

We want to simulate production-like traffic, and in order to do that, we need to have a large variety of requests replayed from production logs.

In turn, this causes us to have a huge sample dataset. So the questions are:

1. What's the recommended CSV sample size for large input samples?
2. Is CSV Data Config enough to use files that contain 300MB - 500MB or more worth of HTTP request payloads?
3. Can I just increase JVM memory limits?
4. Is this method good enough? Is there a better alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the CSV has no impact on memory usage of JMeter provided you use [CSV Data Set](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

Just don't use the [CSVRead](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function as per the note in documentation.

By the way I see you flagged question as JMeter 3.2, in case you are using it, you should upgrade to [JMeter 4.0](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) which is the most powerful and accurate version.